Why does a ventilator appear to run leftwise and rightwise and back when spinning up?
My university professor, a friend of mine, asked me: "Do you know why, when a ventilator starts and during the process up to final speed, it runs clockwise and anticlockwise and back again to clockwise?"
"Why?" I replied. He told me: "It is the retina that has a detection delay and creates that effect!"
When I was a kid, I saw that effect hundred of times in the kitchen! The ventilator started running clockwise, it stopped and reversed running anticlockwise, and clockwise again and eventually anticlockwise again!
I had never thought about it but I didn't feel his explanation was correct and I told him: "No! this is not the reason, DO THAT and revert back and tell me what happened! The ventilator does never stop and never reverse!"
The question is: What did I detect and what did I instruct him to experiment? How do I firmly demonstrate that the reason of back and forth was different?

Is "ventilator" like the kitchen vent fans above a stove when you're cooking food? "Retina" in English is a part of your eyeball so I think that must be something else.

@mike1994 "Ventilator" (or variants thereof) is the word for any kind of fan in many languages.

@Puk yes, I just wanted to get clarification on if it's the fan above the stove he is talking about vs. something else.

retina is the back part of the eye that detects light ( at least in Italian language that I am native to - and also in latin languages )

Yes call it fan, any way something that rotates and pushes air !!!

@Chemomechanics Seems like it. When a fan spins up it appears to reverse its direction because of this.

I have tidied up the question.

I think you’re asking about the so-called wagon-wheel effect, which can arise from stroboscopic conditions (image-recoding methods, such as movie cameras, and/or illumination conditions, such as fluorescent lighting) and idiosyncrasies of visual perception. It involves the fan (ventilator) changing speed, as you note, but doesn’t involve the fan actually changing rotation direction; it’s an optical illusion of apparent rotation reversal (or stationarity).

Yes it was fluorescent lighting, and it is an optical illusion (but i works anyway also with incadescent - why ? ), and I told him: open wide the window and let the solar light come into the room, do you see the same effect ?

Search the link for the section beginning with "The first to observe the wagon-wheel effect under truly continuous illumination (such as from the sun) was Schouten" for a discussion with links to the relevant reports.
